# If $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i = 0$ for some large $n$, how many roots does $p(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} ia_ix^{i-1}$ have?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> If $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i = 0$ for some large $n$, how can we show that $p(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} ia_ix^{i-1}$ has at least one real root? Does it necessarily have more than one real root?

Substitute $a_1 = -(a_2 + \cdots + a_n)$ in order to have $p(x) = a_2 (2x-1) + a_3(3x^2-1) + \cdots + a_n (nx^{n-1}-1)$.

If $a_1=0$, we can say that there's at least one real root. I could not do any further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that if we define $q(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix^i$ then $q(0)=q(1)=0$ and $p(x)=q'(x)$. Rolle's theorem implies that $p(x)$ has a root in $(0,1)$.

As for your second question, setting $a_1 = -1$, $a_i = 0$ for $1 < i < n$ and $a_n=1$ we have $p(x)=nx^{n-1}-1$. For even $n$ this polynomial has exactly one real root while for odd $n$ the polynomial has two real roots so we cannot get a better result than what the problem asks for.

Answer (score 4):

Let's define the function $f(x)$
$$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_ix^i $$

Then $f(0) = 0 $ and $f(1) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i = 0 $.

We remark that $p(x) = f'(x)$. Thus, there exists an $x_0 \in (0,1)$ such that $p(x_0)=f'(x_0) = 0$.